# event delegation on parent element for dynamically created child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to attach an on click event to dynamically created li tags to call a function which takes one argument.  The argument to be passed is whatever string is in each li's value property.  Below are snippets of code from my program.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

//this is a sample of the format of data in fileList
{"files":["backups","FilesAndFolders.php"]}

//this data is made usable in the the JS code like so

var extracted = JSON.parse(data);
var fileList = extracted.files;


//the li's are being generated by this code which is called by a main function within the JS script
function pathContents(fileList)
{
 var list = $('<ul/>').addClass('files');
    $.each(fileList, function (_, file) {  
  $('<li/>').addClass('file').attr('value', file).text(file).appendTo(list);
    });
    return list;
}

//after main function gets list back from pathContents() it calls this function
function addOnClickToPathContents(fileList)
{
   $('.files').on('click', '.file', function(){
  var file = fileList[this.value];
  pathBuilder(file);
 });
}
```

```html
<ul class="files">
 <li value="backups" class="file">backups</li>
 <li value="FilesAndFolders.php" class="file">FilesAndFolders.php</li>
</ul>
```

The problem with this code is it's assigning the event to the ul rather than to each li.  Is there a way to modify it so it assigns the on click event to each child li?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem is that `li` element has no property called `value`, `this.value` will always return 0. Instead, you can use `attr()` method:

```
$('.files').on('click', '.file', function(){
    var file = $(this).attr("value");
    pathBuilder(file);
});
```

If you want to access the file from your `fileList` array by using the `li` index, you can use `index()` method:

```
$('.files').on('click', '.file', function(){
    var file = fileList[$(this).index()];
    pathBuilder(file);
});
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: In the pathContents() function .attr('value', file) is used to assign a value.  It appears in the li tags in the HTML code snippet.  Why isn't the value being displayed in the li tag being recognized by the JS in addOnClickToPathContents()?

Comment: Please check out the updated answer! However, with some more explanation on your specific issue, I may be able to assist you in better alternatives.

Comment: I tried the `var file = fileList[$(this).index()];` but it is still assigning the on click even to the ul instead of to the child li elements.

Comment: Here is a working demo https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/xxv7nLv1/ Please check it out.

Comment: Yes, the demo works fine.  And now my code works too!  Fabulous!  What was throwing me off was where the event symbol was being displayed in the Inspector in Firefox.  It shows it on the event rather than for each li but the li's in the browser respond as they are supposed to when clicked on.

Comment: The last line of the previous comment should read "It shows the event on the ul rather than for each li...".